# How to prevent preloader image view in URL preview? I want to see main image of news (or blogs) in URL preview

Tags: html, css, frontend, seo, preloader

I use preloader in website: https://adl.az/

The file format of the preloader image is "PNG". It's not "GIF".

## The Problem is:

If I send website URL to anyone or share it on any social network, I see the preloader image in the URL preview. But this is not true, because it is supposed to display the organization logo. Or if I'm sharing a single news (or blog) as a post, it should show the main image of the news (blog) in the post (I mean the URL preview).

Visually,

## The current situation:

[image: current-situation]

## Required:

[image: required-situation]

I tried to convert it to "svg" but with no good result. So I didn't change the file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have any Open Graph tags  in your home page..so facebook took one screenshot of the page https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/online-marketing/social-media/open-graph/

and another thing...your site have `<html lang="en"` but is not in english, this can confuse google.

The same problem in the news page, but fortunatly facebook is enought smart to take a picture from the html article tag, in case you have more than an image he can take one you wouldn't like, is always raccomended to use Open Graph data for socials sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your homepage has links to icons:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
```

All these sizes contradict [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search#guidelines):

> Your favicon must be a multiple of 48px square, for example: 48x48px,
> 96x96px, 144x144px and so on.

Also, all the icons listed in your [web manifest](https://adl.az/assets/images/favicon/manifest.json) are not available.